# Programatically open to the google play services page for my app

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-play-games

If i start up the 'Play Games' icon on the android and goto My Games, i can click on my app to get to the page about it.  Is it possible to programatically go here when a user clicks a button in my app?

NOTE: I dont want to open the app on the Google Play Store!, this is the app page in the Game Play Services I want!

Comment: No, i dont want to open the google play STORE, i want to open the google GAME PLAY SERVICE page, please read the question before down grading it

Comment: `startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.gms")));`

Answer (score -1):

If you want to link to your products from an Android app, create an Intent that opens an Google Play URL, as shown in the example below.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setData(Uri.parse("market://details?id=com.example.android"));
startActivity(intent);
```

for More information go through [link](http://developer.android.com/distribute/googleplay/promote/linking.html#android-app)

Comment: This is the play store, NOT the game play services